# Record USB mic and Skype separately

Tags: microphone, mixing, usb, podcasts

I'd like to record a conversation between myself in a studio, and an interviewee calling in remotely (over Skype, Zoom etc - ideally I'd like it to be agnostic of the video conference software for maximum flexibility), to be produced into a podcast.

I'd like to record my voice separately to the interviewee, so that I can adjust volume levels, filter etc. individually in post and not have to worry about getting levels right during the recording.

I have access to a really nice USB microphone (Blue Yeti) to use for my end, so I'd like to use that. I have no control over what the interviewee has - eg they may only be using a built in laptop mic, and they may be non technical, so I can't ask them to record on their end.

What I can't understand is - how do I set this up? Ideally the whole setup should be relatively portable.

If I just try to record in Audacity on a laptop, with my USB mic plugged in and talking over Skype, I can either record just my mic, or both mixed together, but not the mic and interviewee separately (unless I'm missing something?)

I've also successfully tried using 2 laptops - one running the Skype call and recording my mic, with the headphone socket plugged into an external soundcard, which feeds the interviewee Skype audio into the second laptop over USB. That way I can record separately, but I'd really rather not have to use two laptops (twice the chance of one crashing mid record, and much less portable).

**I've read a lot about mixers and digital audio recorders, but the problem is the ALL USE XLR MICS, not USB mics.**

Any advice or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello. What operating system are you using on your laptop ?

Comment: There are some suggestions for loopback/system audio recording on the Audacity site, though I'm not sure if the USB mic sound will be included in that. https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_windows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution. Using OBS Studio. I found a video explaining how to record separate audio tracks for microphone and desktop, save to MKV (supports multi track, and can be recovered if computer crashes) then import into audacity. It works!